# nested tibbles: printing results from regressions

Tags: r

I am trying to print the results from a nested tibble regression.

The data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Quintiles  Reg_sum         
  <chr>      <list>          
1 quintile_5 <S3: summary.lm>
2 quintile_1 <S3: summary.lm>
3 quintile_4 <S3: summary.lm>
```

So I want to filter by a quintile and print the results of the regression.

```
r %>%
  filter(Quintiles == "quintile_5") %>%
  print(Reg_sum)
```

I have tried a variation of the above with `print(summary(Reg_sum))` etc. without luck. How can I print to the console the results of the regression like (`summary(myregmodel)`) ?

Simply doing `r$Reg_sum` gives me the regression outputs but I want to filter first.

Comment: You may either need `r %>%
  filter(Quintiles == "quintile_5")  %>% pull(Reg_sum)` or `%>% .$Reg_sum %>% print`

Comment: Yep! that worked, thanks! (both methods worked on the full data)

Comment: As a side note: is it possible to name the regressions from which "quintile" they came from? instead of `[[1]], [[2]]...[[N]]`?

Comment: Try with `set_names` updated the solution

Comment: I can't test your example as it is showing some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to `pull` the column

```
r %>%
    filter(Quintiles == "quintile_5") %>% 
    pull(Reg_sum)
```

---

But, the base R extraction `$` also can be done

```
r %>%
    filter(Quintiles == "quintile_5")  %>%
    .$Reg_sum
```

---

If we need to `name`, then use `set_names` before `pull`ing the column

```
r %>%
    filter(Quintiles == "quintile_5") %>%
    mutate(Reg_sum = set_names(Reg_sum, Quintiles)) %>% 
    pull(Reg_sum)
```

Comment: well, if base ... ```r[r$Quintiles =="quintile_5","Reg_sum"]```?

Comment: @M-M With a `,` after the expression